# Android string.xml error for every character I type

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, ide

I am going through the android hello world tutorial, and have been stuck when trying to create an XML UI.  For some reason, even on a new program, in which I have made no changes to the default build, it gives the error java.lang.NullPointerException after every character I type.  I can't figure out why it is doing this, as I am just trying to edit the text between the Text  I want to set it to say something other than what is set by default.  However, even with a fresh build, no changes, and I just try to change the text within the xml tags, it still gives the error.  What do I need to do to allow it to let me type? I am using the eclips IDE and the android sdk.  I was able to do the first part of the tutorial that doesn't involve XML.

Comment: A code snippet will help solve the problem. Also check if the eclipse plugin and the SDK installation is done right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the answer somewhere else, it was something wrong with how the file was created by default. I have to add the element xmlns:android as follows

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Interestingly enough, the file will work if I type it one character at a time, dismissing the pop up with each keystroke. However the new element eliminates the pop ups. I am not sure why the error would pop up, yet the program still compile and run correctly on my avd. Oh well, if you have this error add the element and it goes away

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but I suspect you are doing something like the following:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello" />
```

and you are editing it to

```
<TextView android:text="@string/helloWorld" />
```

without creating a reference in `res/values/strings.xml` .

If this is the case, go to strings.xml and edit the proper string there, for example

```
<string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
```

becomes

```
<string name="hello">Hello everybody!</string>
```

Comment: I didn't edit the main.xml file at all.  
I also didn't edit the actual name element either.  All I attempted to do was change the text between the <string name="hello"> and </string> tags.  It pops up the error with each character I type.

Comment: Actually, I noticed it doesn't matter where I type in this file, it will pop up the same error no matter where I type.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your typing contain UTF-8 not pure ASCII. You can change in eclipse by
in Ecipse IDE   Window> preference> Under General tab, select workspace.
In text file encoding choose other, in these choose UTF-8 . It will be ok